# how to change color of navigation icon and default text of ActionMode

Tags: android, android-actionmode

I want to change the color of navigation icon's color of ActionMode.I can change color of ActionMode Background but I don't know how to change the color of ActionMode Navigation.

Image : https://ibb.co/tP1p90T

I want to change color of back navigation and selected number indicator.

ActionMode class :

```
  private class ActionModeCallback implements ActionMode.Callback {
        @Override
        public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
            Tools.setSystemBarColor(MainActivity.this, R.color.colorDarkBlue2);
            mode.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_delete, menu);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
            int id = item.getItemId();
            if (id == R.id.action_delete) {
                deleteInboxes();
                mode.finish();
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {
            recycleAdapter.clearSelections();
            actionMode = null;
            Tools.setSystemBarColor(MainActivity.this, R.color.colorPrimary);
        }
    }
```

Tools class :

```
public class Tools {

    public static void setSystemBarColor(Activity act, @ColorRes int color) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            Window window = act.getWindow();
            window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
            window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
            window.setStatusBarColor(act.getResources().getColor(color));
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can change color of `ActionMode` like

### Way 1 (more customization)

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    ...

    <!--<item name="actionModeBackground">@color/colorAccent</item>--> <!-- 1 option to change background of ActionMode -->

    <item name="actionModeStyle">@style/ActionModeStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="ActionModeStyle" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionMode">
    <item name="background">@color/colorAccent</item> <!-- 2 option to change background of ActionMode -->
    <item name="titleTextStyle">@style/ActionModeTitleStyle</item>
    <item name="closeItemLayout">@layout/layout_close</item> 
</style>

<style name="ActionModeTitleStyle">
    <item name="android:textSize">20sp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#0f0</item> 
</style>
```

**layout_close.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ImageView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
           xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
           xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:id="@+id/action_mode_close_button"
           style="?attr/actionModeCloseButtonStyle"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"
           android:layout_marginEnd="16dip"
           android:layout_marginRight="16dip"
           android:clickable="true"
           android:focusable="true"
           android:paddingStart="8dp"
           android:paddingEnd="8dp"
           android:tint="#00f"
           app:srcCompat="?attr/actionModeCloseDrawable" tools:ignore="ContentDescription"/>
```

**Result**

[image]

### Way 2

You can consider to change your main application them (if possible).
Example, now I think you are using `Theme.AppCompat.Light`, so the navigation icon and title color is `BLACK`

If you change your theme to `Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar` and `Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar`, your navigation icon and title color will become `WHITE`

Example result of `Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar`

[image]

Hope it help

Comment: I did make custom style for actionMode but it didn't work , maybe because there is no layout for give that style . and thank you for second way , I learn something new

Comment: I'm quite sure that way 1 will work because I did it (with result image). Can you post it in your question again and I can check if why it not work in your case?